# How browsers will convert mixins to regular css

Tags: css, sass, less

In Less and Sass we make use of lots of mixins, how does the browser compile or converts those mixins to regular CSS and apply those styles?

Comment: browsers dont, interpreters/compilers that generate your final CSS do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser DOES NOT convert `pre-processed` (LESS, SCSS, Compass) CSS rules.

You need to use a build script/compiler BEFORE linking a normal CSS file to your HTML. This process converts SCSS/LESS -> CSS for your browser to render.

You can use [Webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader), [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass), [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass), or even [desktop/GUI tools](https://prepros.io/) to do this.

You can also use a javascript parser to inject the final CSS into the page `onLoad` but this has performance implications and IS NOT recommended.